# show first quiz item on page load

Tags: jquery, pageload

Is there a quick easy way, from the code I have provided, to load the first question of the multiple choice quiz instead of showing the "Start Quiz" button?

```
(function($){

// Setup Sexy Quiz
$.slickQuiz = function(element, options) {
    var $element = $(element),
        element = element;

    var plugin = this;

    var defaults = {
        checkAnswerText:  'See Answer &raquo;',
        nextQuestionText: 'Next Question &raquo;',
        backButtonText: '',
        randomSort: true,
        randomSortQuestions: true,
        randomSortAnswers: true,
        preventUnanswered: false,
        completionResponseMessaging: false,
        disableResponseMessaging: false
    };

    // Reassign user-submitted deprecated options
    var depMsg = '';

    if (options && typeof options.disableNext != 'undefined') {
        if (typeof options.preventUnanswered == 'undefined') {
            options.preventUnanswered = options.disableNext;
        }
        depMsg += 'The \'disableNext\' option has been deprecated, please use \'preventUnanswered\' in it\'s place.\n\n';
    }

    if (depMsg != '') {
        if (typeof console != 'undefined') {
            console.warn(depMsg);
        } else {
            alert(depMsg);
        }
    }
    // End of deprecation reassignment

    plugin.config = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var selector = $(element).attr('id');

    var triggers = {
        starter:         '#' + selector + ' .startQuiz',
        checker:         '#' + selector + ' .checkAnswer',
        next:            '#' + selector + ' .nextQuestion',
        back:            '#' + selector + ' .backToQuestion'
    }

    var targets = {
        quizName:        '#' + selector + ' .quizName',
        quizArea:        '#' + selector + ' .quizArea',
        quizResults:     '#' + selector + ' .quizResults',
        quizResultsCopy: '#' + selector + ' .quizResultsCopy',
        quizHeader:      '#' + selector + ' .quizHeader',
        quizScore:       '#' + selector + ' .quizScore',
        quizLevel:       '#' + selector + ' .quizLevel'
    }

    // Set via json option or quizJSON variable (see slickQuiz-config.js)
    var quizValues = (plugin.config.json ? plugin.config.json : typeof quizJSON != 'undefined' ? quizJSON : null);

    var questions = plugin.config.randomSort || plugin.config.randomSortQuestions ?
                    quizValues.questions.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }) :
                    quizValues.questions;

    var levels = {
        1: quizValues.info.level1, // 80-100%
        2: quizValues.info.level2, // 60-79%
        3: quizValues.info.level3, // 40-59%
        4: quizValues.info.level4, // 20-39%
        5: quizValues.info.level5  // 0-19%
    }

    // Count the number of questions
    var questionCount = questions.length;

    plugin.method = {
        // Sets up the questions and answers based on above array
        setupQuiz: function() {
            $(targets.quizName).hide().html(quizValues.info.name).fadeIn(1000);
            $(targets.quizHeader).hide().prepend(quizValues.info.main).fadeIn(1000);
            $(targets.quizResultsCopy).append(quizValues.info.results);

            // Setup questions
            var quiz  = $('<ol class="questions"></ol>'),
                count = 1;

            // Loop through questions object
            for (i in questions) {
                if (questions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var question = questions[i];

                    var questionHTML = $('<li class="question" id="question' + (count - 1) + '"></li>');
                    questionHTML.append('<div class="questionCount">Question <span class="current">' + count + '</span> of <span class="total">' + questionCount + '</span></div>');
                    questionHTML.append('<h3>' + count + '. ' + question.q + '</h3>');

                    // Count the number of true values
                    var truths = 0;
                    for (i in question.a) {
                        if (question.a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            var answer = question.a[i];
                            if (answer.correct) {
                                truths++;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    // prepare a name for the answer inputs based on the question
                    var inputName  = 'question' + (count - 1);

                    // Now let's append the answers with checkboxes or radios depending on truth count
                    var answerHTML = $('<ul class="answers"></ul>');

                    var answers = plugin.config.randomSort || plugin.config.randomSortAnswers ?
                        question.a.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }) :
                        question.a;

                    for (i in answers) {
                        if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            var answer   = answers[i],
                                optionId = inputName + '_' + i.toString();

                            // If question has >1 true answers, use checkboxes; otherwise, radios
                            var input = '<input id="' + optionId + '" name="' + inputName
                                + '" type="' + (truths > 1 ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') + '" />';

                            var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';

                            var answerContent = $('<li></li>')
                                .append(input)
                                .append(optionLabel);
                            answerHTML.append(answerContent);
                        }
                    };

                    // Append answers to question
                    questionHTML.append(answerHTML);

                    // If response messaging is NOT disabled, add it
                    if (!plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging) {
                        // Now let's append the correct / incorrect response messages
                        var responseHTML = $('<ul class="responses"></ul>');
                        responseHTML.append('<li class="correct">' + question.correct + '</li>');
                        responseHTML.append('<li class="incorrect">' + question.incorrect + '</li>');

                        // Append responses to question
                        questionHTML.append(responseHTML);
                    }

                    // Appends check answer / back / next question buttons
                    if (plugin.config.backButtonText && plugin.config.backButtonText != '') {
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button backToQuestion">' + plugin.config.backButtonText + '</a>');
                    }

                    // If response messaging is disabled or hidden until the quiz is completed,
                    // make the nextQuestion button the checkAnswer button, as well
                    if (plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging || plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button nextQuestion checkAnswer">' + plugin.config.nextQuestionText + '</a>');
                    } else {
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button nextQuestion">' + plugin.config.nextQuestionText + '</a>');
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button checkAnswer">' + plugin.config.checkAnswerText + '</a>');
                    }

                    // Append question & answers to quiz
                    quiz.append(questionHTML);

                    count++;
                };
            };

            // Add the quiz content to the page
            $(targets.quizArea).append(quiz);

            // Toggle the start button
            $(triggers.starter).fadeIn(500);
        },

        // Starts the quiz (hides start button and displays first question)
        startQuiz: function(startButton) {
            $(startButton).fadeOut(300, function(){
                var firstQuestion = $('#' + selector + ' .questions li').first();
                if (firstQuestion.length) {
                    firstQuestion.fadeIn(500);
                }
            });
        },

        // Validates the response selection(s), displays explanations & next question button
        checkAnswer: function(checkButton) {
            var questionLI   = $($(checkButton).parents('li.question')[0]),
                answerInputs = questionLI.find('input:checked'),
                answers      = questions[parseInt(questionLI.attr('id').replace(/(question)/, ''))].a;

            // Collect the true answers needed for a correct response
            var trueAnswers = [];
            for (i in answers) {
                if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var answer = answers[i];

                    if (answer.correct) {
                        trueAnswers.push(answer.option);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Collect the answers submitted
            var selectedAnswers = []
            answerInputs.each( function() {
                // If we're in jQuery Mobile, grab value from nested span
                if ($('.ui-mobile').length > 0) {
                    var inputValue = $(this).next('label').find('span.ui-btn-text').html();
                } else {
                    var inputValue = $(this).next('label').html();
                }

                selectedAnswers.push(inputValue);
            });

            if (plugin.config.preventUnanswered && selectedAnswers.length == 0) {
                alert('Choose the best possible answer.');
                return false;
            }

            // Verify all true answers (and no false ones) were submitted
            var correctResponse = plugin.method.compareAnswers(trueAnswers, selectedAnswers);

            if (correctResponse) {
                questionLI.addClass('correctResponse');
            }

            // If response messaging hasn't been disabled, toggle the proper response
            if (!plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging) {
                // If response messaging hasn't been set to display upon quiz completion, show it now
                if (!plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                    questionLI.find('.answers').hide();
                    questionLI.find('.responses').show();

                    $(checkButton).hide();
                    questionLI.find('.nextQuestion').fadeIn(300);
                    questionLI.find('.backToQuestion').fadeIn(300);
                }

                // Toggle responses based on submission
                if (correctResponse) {
                    questionLI.find('.correct').fadeIn(300);
                } else {
                    questionLI.find('.incorrect').fadeIn(300);
                }
            }
        },

        // Moves to the next question OR completes the quiz if on last question
        nextQuestion: function(nextButton) {
            var currentQuestion = $($(nextButton).parents('li.question')[0]),
                nextQuestion    = currentQuestion.next('.question'),
                answerInputs    = currentQuestion.find('input:checked');

            // If response messaging has been disabled or moved to completion,
            // make sure we have an answer if we require it, let checkAnswer handle the alert messaging
            if (plugin.config.preventUnanswered && answerInputs.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (nextQuestion.length) {
                currentQuestion.fadeOut(300, function(){
                    nextQuestion.find('.backToQuestion').show().end().fadeIn(500);
                });
            } else {
                plugin.method.completeQuiz();
            }
        },

        // Go back to the last question
        backToQuestion: function(backButton) {
            var questionLI = $($(backButton).parents('li.question')[0]),
                answers    = questionLI.find('.answers');

            // Back to previous question
            if (answers.css('display') === 'block' ) {
                var prevQuestion = questionLI.prev('.question');

                questionLI.fadeOut(300, function() {
                    prevQuestion.removeClass('correctResponse');
                    prevQuestion.find('.responses, .responses li').hide()
                    prevQuestion.find('.answers').show();
                    prevQuestion.find('.checkAnswer').show();

                    // If response messaging hasn't been disabled or moved to completion, hide the next question button
                    // If it has been, we need nextQuestion visible so the user can move forward (there is no separate checkAnswer button)
                    if (!plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging && !plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                        prevQuestion.find('.nextQuestion').hide();
                    }

                    if (prevQuestion.attr('id') != 'question0') {
                        prevQuestion.find('.backToQuestion').show();
                    } else {
                        prevQuestion.find('.backToQuestion').hide();
                    }

                    prevQuestion.fadeIn(500);
                });

            // Back to question from responses
            } else {
                questionLI.find('.responses').fadeOut(300, function(){
                    questionLI.removeClass('correctResponse');
                    questionLI.find('.responses li').hide();
                    answers.fadeIn(500);
                    questionLI.find('.checkAnswer').fadeIn(500);
                    questionLI.find('.nextQuestion').hide();

                    // if question is first, don't show back button on question
                    if (questionLI.attr('id') != 'question0') {
                        questionLI.find('.backToQuestion').show();
                    } else {
                        questionLI.find('.backToQuestion').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        // Hides all questions, displays the final score and some conclusive information
        completeQuiz: function() {
            var score     = $('#' + selector + ' .correctResponse').length,
                levelRank = plugin.method.calculateLevel(score),
                levelText = levels[levelRank];

            $(targets.quizScore + ' span').html(score + ' / ' + questionCount);
            $(targets.quizLevel + ' span').html(levelText);
            $(targets.quizLevel).addClass('level' + levelRank);

            $(targets.quizArea).fadeOut(300, function() {
                // If response messaging is set to show upon quiz completion, show it
                if (plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging && !plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging) {
                    $('#' + selector + ' .questions input').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#' + selector + ' .questions .button, #' + selector + ' .questions .questionCount').hide();
                    $('#' + selector + ' .questions .question, #' + selector + ' .questions .responses').show();
                    $(targets.quizResults).append($('#' + selector + ' .questions')).fadeIn(500);
                } else {
                    $(targets.quizResults).fadeIn(500);
                }
            });
        },

        // Compares selected responses with true answers, returns true if they match exactly
        compareAnswers: function(trueAnswers, selectedAnswers) {
            if (trueAnswers.length != selectedAnswers.length) {
                return false;
            }

            var trueAnswers     = trueAnswers.sort(),
                selectedAnswers = selectedAnswers.sort();

            for (var i = 0, l = trueAnswers.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (trueAnswers[i] !== selectedAnswers[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        },

        // Calculates knowledge level based on number of correct answers
        calculateLevel: function(correctAnswers) {
            var percent = correctAnswers / questionCount,
                level   = 0;

            if (plugin.method.inRange(0, 0.20, percent)) {
                level = 5;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.21, 0.40, percent)) {
                level = 4;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.41, 0.60, percent)) {
                level = 3;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.61, 0.80, percent)) {
                level = 2;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.81, 1.00, percent)) {
                level = 1;
            }

            return level;
        },

        // Determines if percentage of correct values is within a level range
        inRange: function(start, end, value) {
            if (value >= start && value <= end) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    plugin.init = function() {
        // Setup quiz
        plugin.method.setupQuiz();

        // Bind "start" button
        $(triggers.starter).bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.startQuiz(this);
        });

        // Using 'live' instead of 'bind' since these triggers are generated
        // on the fly in setupQuiz and thus won't be available on page load

        // Bind "submit answer" button
        $(triggers.checker).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.checkAnswer(this);
        });

        // Bind "back" button
        $(triggers.back).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.backToQuestion(this);
        });

        // Bind "next question" button
        $(triggers.next).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.nextQuestion(this);
        });
    }

    plugin.init();
}

$.fn.slickQuiz = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (undefined == $(this).data('slickQuiz')) {
            var plugin = new $.slickQuiz(this, options);
            $(this).data('slickQuiz', plugin);
        }
    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function($){
// Setup Sexy Quiz
$.slickQuiz = function(element, options) {
    var $element = $(element),
         element = element;

    var plugin = this;

    var defaults = {
        checkAnswerText:  'See Answer &raquo;',
        nextQuestionText: 'Next Question &raquo;',
        backButtonText: '',
        randomSort: true,
        randomSortQuestions: true,
        randomSortAnswers: true,
        preventUnanswered: false,
        completionResponseMessaging: false,
        disableResponseMessaging: false
    };

    // Reassign user-submitted deprecated options
    var depMsg = '';

    if (options && typeof options.disableNext != 'undefined') {
        if (typeof options.preventUnanswered == 'undefined') {
            options.preventUnanswered = options.disableNext;
        }
        depMsg += 'The \'disableNext\' option has been deprecated, please use \'preventUnanswered\' in it\'s place.\n\n';
    }

    if (depMsg != '') {
        if (typeof console != 'undefined') {
            console.warn(depMsg);
        } else {
            alert(depMsg);
        }
    }
    // End of deprecation reassignment

    plugin.config = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var selector = $(element).attr('id');

    var triggers = {
        //starter:         '#' + selector + ' .startQuiz',
        checker:         '#' + selector + ' .checkAnswer',
        next:            '#' + selector + ' .nextQuestion',
        back:            '#' + selector + ' .backToQuestion'
    }

    var targets = {
        quizName:        '#' + selector + ' .quizName',
        quizArea:        '#' + selector + ' .quizArea',
        quizResults:     '#' + selector + ' .quizResults',
        quizResultsCopy: '#' + selector + ' .quizResultsCopy',
        quizHeader:      '#' + selector + ' .quizHeader',
        quizScore:       '#' + selector + ' .quizScore',
        quizLevel:       '#' + selector + ' .quizLevel'
    }

    // Set via json option or quizJSON variable (see slickQuiz-config.js)
    var quizValues = (plugin.config.json ? plugin.config.json : typeof quizJSON != 'undefined' ? quizJSON : null);

    var questions = plugin.config.randomSort || plugin.config.randomSortQuestions ?
                    quizValues.questions.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }) :
                    quizValues.questions;

    var levels = {
        1: quizValues.info.level1, // 80-100%
        2: quizValues.info.level2, // 60-79%
        3: quizValues.info.level3, // 40-59%
        4: quizValues.info.level4, // 20-39%
        5: quizValues.info.level5  // 0-19%
    }

    // Count the number of questions
    var questionCount = questions.length;

    plugin.method = {
        // Sets up the questions and answers based on above array
        setupQuiz: function() {
            $(targets.quizName).hide().html(quizValues.info.name).fadeIn(1000);
            $(targets.quizHeader).hide().prepend(quizValues.info.main).fadeIn(1000);
            $(targets.quizResultsCopy).append(quizValues.info.results);

            // Setup questions
            var quiz  = $('<ol class="questions"></ol>'),
                count = 1;

            // Loop through questions object
            for (i in questions) {
                if (questions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var question = questions[i];

                    var questionHTML = $('<li class="question" id="question' + (count - 1) + '"></li>');
                    questionHTML.append('<div class="questionCount">Question <span class="current">' + count + '</span> of <span class="total">' + questionCount + '</span></div>');
                    questionHTML.append('<h3>' + count + '. ' + question.q + '</h3>');

                    // Count the number of true values
                    var truths = 0;
                    for (i in question.a) {
                        if (question.a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            var answer = question.a[i];
                            if (answer.correct) {
                                truths++;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    // prepare a name for the answer inputs based on the question
                    var inputName  = 'question' + (count - 1);

                    // Now let's append the answers with checkboxes or radios depending on truth count
                    var answerHTML = $('<ul class="answers"></ul>');

                    var answers = plugin.config.randomSort || plugin.config.randomSortAnswers ?
                        question.a.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }) :
                        question.a;

                    for (i in answers) {
                        if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            var answer   = answers[i],
                                optionId = inputName + '_' + i.toString();

                            // If question has >1 true answers, use checkboxes; otherwise, radios
                            var input = '<input id="' + optionId + '" name="' + inputName
                                + '" type="' + (truths > 1 ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') + '" />';

                            var optionLabel = '<label for="' + optionId + '">' + answer.option + '</label>';

                            var answerContent = $('<li></li>')
                                .append(input)
                                .append(optionLabel);
                            answerHTML.append(answerContent);
                        }
                    };

                    // Append answers to question
                    questionHTML.append(answerHTML);

                    // If response messaging is NOT disabled, add it
                    if (!plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging) {
                        // Now let's append the correct / incorrect response messages
                        var responseHTML = $('<ul class="responses"></ul>');
                        responseHTML.append('<li class="correct">' + question.correct + '</li>');
                        responseHTML.append('<li class="incorrect">' + question.incorrect + '</li>');

                        // Append responses to question
                        questionHTML.append(responseHTML);
                    }

                    // Appends check answer / back / next question buttons
                    if (plugin.config.backButtonText && plugin.config.backButtonText != '') {
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button backToQuestion">' + plugin.config.backButtonText + '</a>');
                    }

                    // If response messaging is disabled or hidden until the quiz is completed,
                    // make the nextQuestion button the checkAnswer button, as well
                    if (plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging || plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button nextQuestion checkAnswer">' + plugin.config.nextQuestionText + '</a>');
                    } else {
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button nextQuestion">' + plugin.config.nextQuestionText + '</a>');
                        questionHTML.append('<a href="" class="button checkAnswer">' + plugin.config.checkAnswerText + '</a>');
                    }

                    // Append question & answers to quiz
                    quiz.append(questionHTML);

                    count++;
                };
            };

            // Add the quiz content to the page
            $(targets.quizArea).append(quiz);

            // Toggle the start button
            // $(triggers.starter).fadeIn(500);
        },

        // Starts the quiz (hides start button and displays first question)
        startQuiz: function(startButton) {
            var firstQuestion = $('#' + selector + ' .questions li').first();
            if (firstQuestion.length) {
                firstQuestion.fadeIn(500);
            }
        },

        // Validates the response selection(s), displays explanations & next question button
        checkAnswer: function(checkButton) {
            var questionLI   = $($(checkButton).parents('li.question')[0]),
                answerInputs = questionLI.find('input:checked'),
                answers      = questions[parseInt(questionLI.attr('id').replace(/(question)/, ''))].a;

            // Collect the true answers needed for a correct response
            var trueAnswers = [];
            for (i in answers) {
                if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var answer = answers[i];

                    if (answer.correct) {
                        trueAnswers.push(answer.option);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Collect the answers submitted
            var selectedAnswers = []
            answerInputs.each( function() {
                // If we're in jQuery Mobile, grab value from nested span
                if ($('.ui-mobile').length > 0) {
                    var inputValue = $(this).next('label').find('span.ui-btn-text').html();
                } else {
                    var inputValue = $(this).next('label').html();
                }

                selectedAnswers.push(inputValue);
            });

            if (plugin.config.preventUnanswered && selectedAnswers.length == 0) {
                alert('Choose the best possible answer.');
                return false;
            }

            // Verify all true answers (and no false ones) were submitted
            var correctResponse = plugin.method.compareAnswers(trueAnswers, selectedAnswers);

            if (correctResponse) {
                questionLI.addClass('correctResponse');
            }

            // If response messaging hasn't been disabled, toggle the proper response
            if (!plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging) {
                // If response messaging hasn't been set to display upon quiz completion, show it now
                if (!plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                    questionLI.find('.answers').hide();
                    questionLI.find('.responses').show();

                    $(checkButton).hide();
                    questionLI.find('.nextQuestion').fadeIn(300);
                    questionLI.find('.backToQuestion').fadeIn(300);
                }

                // Toggle responses based on submission
                if (correctResponse) {
                    questionLI.find('.correct').fadeIn(300);
                } else {
                    questionLI.find('.incorrect').fadeIn(300);
                }
            }
        },

        // Moves to the next question OR completes the quiz if on last question
        nextQuestion: function(nextButton) {
            var currentQuestion = $($(nextButton).parents('li.question')[0]),
                nextQuestion    = currentQuestion.next('.question'),
                answerInputs    = currentQuestion.find('input:checked');

            // If response messaging has been disabled or moved to completion,
            // make sure we have an answer if we require it, let checkAnswer handle the alert messaging
            if (plugin.config.preventUnanswered && answerInputs.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            if (nextQuestion.length) {
                currentQuestion.fadeOut(300, function(){
                    nextQuestion.find('.backToQuestion').show().end().fadeIn(500);
                });
            } else {
                plugin.method.completeQuiz();
            }
        },

        // Go back to the last question
        backToQuestion: function(backButton) {
            var questionLI = $($(backButton).parents('li.question')[0]),
                answers    = questionLI.find('.answers');

            // Back to previous question
            if (answers.css('display') === 'block' ) {
                var prevQuestion = questionLI.prev('.question');

                questionLI.fadeOut(300, function() {
                    prevQuestion.removeClass('correctResponse');
                    prevQuestion.find('.responses, .responses li').hide()
                    prevQuestion.find('.answers').show();
                    prevQuestion.find('.checkAnswer').show();

                    // If response messaging hasn't been disabled or moved to completion, hide the next question button
                    // If it has been, we need nextQuestion visible so the user can move forward (there is no separate checkAnswer button)
                    if (!plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging && !plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging) {
                        prevQuestion.find('.nextQuestion').hide();
                    }

                    if (prevQuestion.attr('id') != 'question0') {
                        prevQuestion.find('.backToQuestion').show();
                    } else {
                        prevQuestion.find('.backToQuestion').hide();
                    }

                    prevQuestion.fadeIn(500);
                });

            // Back to question from responses
            } else {
                questionLI.find('.responses').fadeOut(300, function(){
                    questionLI.removeClass('correctResponse');
                    questionLI.find('.responses li').hide();
                    answers.fadeIn(500);
                    questionLI.find('.checkAnswer').fadeIn(500);
                    questionLI.find('.nextQuestion').hide();

                    // if question is first, don't show back button on question
                    if (questionLI.attr('id') != 'question0') {
                        questionLI.find('.backToQuestion').show();
                    } else {
                        questionLI.find('.backToQuestion').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        // Hides all questions, displays the final score and some conclusive information
        completeQuiz: function() {
            var score     = $('#' + selector + ' .correctResponse').length,
                levelRank = plugin.method.calculateLevel(score),
                levelText = levels[levelRank];

            $(targets.quizScore + ' span').html(score + ' / ' + questionCount);
            $(targets.quizLevel + ' span').html(levelText);
            $(targets.quizLevel).addClass('level' + levelRank);

            $(targets.quizArea).fadeOut(300, function() {
                // If response messaging is set to show upon quiz completion, show it
                if (plugin.config.completionResponseMessaging && !plugin.config.disableResponseMessaging) {
                    $('#' + selector + ' .questions input').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#' + selector + ' .questions .button, #' + selector + ' .questions .questionCount').hide();
                    $('#' + selector + ' .questions .question, #' + selector + ' .questions .responses').show();
                    $(targets.quizResults).append($('#' + selector + ' .questions')).fadeIn(500);
                } else {
                    $(targets.quizResults).fadeIn(500);
                }
            });
        },

        // Compares selected responses with true answers, returns true if they match exactly
        compareAnswers: function(trueAnswers, selectedAnswers) {
            if (trueAnswers.length != selectedAnswers.length) {
                return false;
            }

            var trueAnswers     = trueAnswers.sort(),
                selectedAnswers = selectedAnswers.sort();

            for (var i = 0, l = trueAnswers.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (trueAnswers[i] !== selectedAnswers[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        },

        // Calculates knowledge level based on number of correct answers
        calculateLevel: function(correctAnswers) {
            var percent = correctAnswers / questionCount,
                level   = 0;

            if (plugin.method.inRange(0, 0.20, percent)) {
                level = 5;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.21, 0.40, percent)) {
                level = 4;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.41, 0.60, percent)) {
                level = 3;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.61, 0.80, percent)) {
                level = 2;
            } else if (plugin.method.inRange(0.81, 1.00, percent)) {
                level = 1;
            }

            return level;
        },

        // Determines if percentage of correct values is within a level range
        inRange: function(start, end, value) {
            if (value >= start && value <= end) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    plugin.init = function() {
        // Setup quiz
        plugin.method.setupQuiz();

        plugin.method.startQuiz(this);

        // Using 'live' instead of 'bind' since these triggers are generated
        // on the fly in setupQuiz and thus won't be available on page load

        // Bind "submit answer" button
        $(triggers.checker).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.checkAnswer(this);
        });

        // Bind "back" button
        $(triggers.back).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.backToQuestion(this);
        });

        // Bind "next question" button
        $(triggers.next).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            plugin.method.nextQuestion(this);
        });
    }

    plugin.init();
}

$.fn.slickQuiz = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (undefined == $(this).data('slickQuiz')) {
            var plugin = new $.slickQuiz(this, options);
            $(this).data('slickQuiz', plugin);
        }
    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I saw that you removed the code that show `startButton` but didn't make the call to `startQuiz` method, so how can the quiz start?

Comment: Thank you both for the help. This one worked like a charm. I can't even begin to tell you why or how, lol. This type of coding is so superior to me. Appreciate the resolution VERY much. Take care and happy new year.

Comment: I see, you call `startQuiz` in `plugin.init` section, sorry for asking stupid question :)

Comment: Cudos to ya both. Wish I knew how to code and read this type of language.

Answer (score 0):

After take a look at your plugin, I came with a solution. First, take a look at this snippet, this function will start your quiz. It take a selector to `start button`, hide that button and show the quiz.

```
// Starts the quiz (hides start button and displays first question)
    startQuiz: function(startButton) {
        $(startButton).fadeOut(300, function(){
            var firstQuestion = $('#' + selector + ' .questions li').first();
            if (firstQuestion.length) {
                firstQuestion.fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    },
```

We will modify this function, remove the `startButton` argument because we don't need to hide it anymore, we also remove the part that hide the start button and keep the part that show the first question:

```
    startQuiz: function() {           
        var firstQuestion = $('#' + selector + ' .questions li').first();
        if (firstQuestion.length) {
            firstQuestion.fadeIn(500);
        }            
    },
```

Second, in `plugin.init`, found this code

```
    // Bind "start" button
    $(triggers.starter).bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        plugin.method.startQuiz(this);
    });
```

This code bind the `startQuiz` function to `start button`. Since you want to show the quiz in start up, you can remove or comment this.

In `plugin.method`, notice the `setupQuiz` function. At the end of this function, it display the `start button` as following:

```
        // Toggle the start button
        $(triggers.starter).fadeIn(500);
```

Because you want to show the question instead of the start button, we will call to `startQuiz` method instead of show the start button, replace that line of code with follwo:

```
plugin.method.startQuiz();
```

and we finish with the modify. Now this plugin should show the first question instead of start button.